# SQL row and count using for loop

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm making a query that will return a multiple of rows, I need to find a way to loop through these rows and extract a value from each row.

How can I make a for loop that will start from the first row and end at the last ?

```
repo = findbyID
for (int i = ? ; i = ? ; ? ) // Id's are not in order and can be somthing like 5,2,10,12...
```

Comment: Your title mentions count. Do you want to also return some counts of some kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I had to make the object passed to the method of type List. Then I had to figure out a way to loop through this list, so I used for loop, ex:

```
for (InvoiceDTO invoices : invoiceDTO) {
//your code
}
```

Now, problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems a little bit off. Perhaps you want something like this:

```
List<Item> items = itemRepository.findAll();
items.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getId()));
```

You could also explicitly specify the order, by convention, in the method name itself, if you’re using Spring Data:

```
List<Item> items = itemRepository.findAllByOrderByIdAsc();
items.forEach(System.out.println(item -> item.getId()));
```

Comment: Let's say the ID's were 10 , 20 ,92 .... 

Looping through these id's will not be beneficial if use increment by 1 in my for loop statement. what should be the correct wat of looping through such id's

Comment: It makes no difference what the ID values are. They will always return from the repo in order if you use findAllByOrderByIdAsc. And you would not need to use a for loop if you were to instead use forEach.

Comment: Does he mean column ids or DTO ids ? is he tryiny to return a java.sql.ResultSet or is he receiving through some framework with a DTO ?